Mapping complex objects to other similar complex objects
I am working on two applications that serve the same purpose. The first application is more feature rich and its types are more complex, but uses old technologies and will be retired. It will eventually be replaced by the second application which is now lacking some of the features in the first application and (currently) has simpler types.
I now have to implement a functionality that would allow users to migrate their data from the first application to the second one. This won't be a database migration, but a migration each user can opt for whenever they are ready to switch. The data will be passed from the first application to the second application through an API and it will be deserialized into the types of the first application which then need to be converted to the types of the second application.
There is a one to one relationship between the types of the two applications, but the types are quite complex and in some cases significantly different from each other. For example, a type of the first application may have 10 members, out of which 3 are strings, 5 are classes/structs and 2 are lists while the corresponding type of the second application may have just 5 members out of which 2 are strings, 2 are classes/structs and just one is a list.
The types in the first application will always be more complex than the types in the second application. So if a member of a first application type is populated, but that member does not have a correspondent in the second application type then the conversion will not be done. Also, the types of the second application will evolve in time as missing features are added to the second application.
I have looked at mappers like AutoMapper but that makes assumptions that are not satisfied by the types in the two applications (e.g. destination type member names follow the exact name of the source type, flattening complex models into simple ones, etc.). I have also though about using the Adapter pattern but these are just simple data types with no behavior so I think that would add complexity that I do not need. So right now I am just thinking about adding extensions methods on the first application type that will convert it to the second application type, but I was wondering if there are any known patterns that should be applied when converting a large number of data types or simply any other better ways of doing this?

I think whether there's an appropriate pattern for this depends on how self-similar your source object ontology is.
Basically, if your types are all different from each other and there are no recurring sub-problems to be solved - if it's just "one damn thing after another" - then there's little you can do except code one adapter after another. You might make them all implement the same UpwardCompatible interface with a toVersion2() method, but the effort stays the same.
The opposite end of the scale would be if they are in a hierarchical relationship (either composition or inheritance), or have a lot of fields, structures etc in common. For instance, many business entities have recurring properties such as identifiers, addresses, management handles etc. that always map the new world in the same way. Then there is sense in writing e.g. one big Migrator that deals with all old types in a unified way, or perhaps just offers convenience methods that make writing the individual adapters easier and more consistent.
